# Advanced custom fields excerpt limit character length

Tags: php, wordpress, trim, advanced-custom-fields

Right now i have an excerpt that outputs 82 words (ACF excerpt) from each of parent pages that i have.
I would like to output instead 400 characters from each page since right now one output have like 400+characters (82words) and another one have 500+characters (82words) and it looks really weird.
I have looked at stackoverflow and codex but not been able to find an solution.

functions.php

```
function tjanster_sida_excerpt($title) {

  global $post;
  $text = get_field($title);
  if ( '' != $text ) {
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
    $excerpt_length = 82; // words
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . ' ');
    $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
  }
  return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $text);
}
```

my-template.php

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
'order'          => 'ASC',
'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
);

$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
    <article>

        <header>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </header>

        <?php
        global $more;
        $more = 0;
        ?>
        <p><?php echo tjanster_sida_excerpt('redigerare'); ?></p>

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-readmore">Read more</a>

    </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

How do i trim it to 400 characters ?

Comment: Have you used `sub_str(0, 400);`? http://php.net/substr